# Filter specific key from json string

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsstring

I have jsonString that comes from array and it looks something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *tempListArray = [NSMutableArray new];

    for (VideoListData *obj in self.listArray) {
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [obj convertotDict:obj];
        [tempListArray addObject:dict];
    }

    NSError *writeError = nil;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:tempListArray options:0 error:&writeError];

NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

It contains data something like this in json format:

```
[
{
"ImageUrl":"...",
"Duration":0,
"PlaylistId":"",
"Content":"...",
"LastPlayTime":0,
"VideoId":"5"
},
{
"ImageUrl":"...",
"Duration":0,
"PlaylistId":"",
"Content":"...",
"LastPlayTime":0,
"VideoId":"1959"
}
]
```

How can I filter only the key "VideoId" and have it in another new jsonString? Or is it better to filter it in array form? So it should look something like this:

```
[
{
"VideoId":"5"
},
{
"VideoId":"1959"
}
]
```

Comment: Why are you bothering with JSON? You already have your VideoListData objects in an array. Why not create the desired array/dictionary data with just the desired value?

Comment: Do you want an array of dictionaries of strings (as in your post) or an array of strings?

Comment: you need only videoId in one single array right ?

Comment: `[tempListArray valueForKeyPath:@"VideoId"]` should return `["5","1959"]`, it's in a simplified "format", returning simple array of videoId, and not array of dictionaries with only one key...

Answer (score 0):

You already have it in the array. So normally access the index value like. First get the ID, then if you want to use it further, create a dictionary, add the MyVideoId each time and each dictionary in array. First get the VideoId.

try it:

```
NSString *MyVideoId=[[tempListArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"VideoId"];
```

Or if you want it from current state, try it:

```
NSMutableArray *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                      options:0 error:NULL];


NSString *MyVideoId=[[jsonObject objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"VideoId"];
```

You will add like, you will have it inside a loop. Declare myNewarra outside of loop and tempDict inside the loop.

```
NSMutableArray *myNewarra=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSDictionary *tempDict=[[NSDictionary alloc] init];
[tempDict setValue:MyVideoId forKey:@"VideoId"];
[myNewarra addObject:tempDict];
```